# Is it possible to transfer files from windows 7 to ubuntu? using dual boot

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read ext4 and btrfs partitions in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-and-btrfs-partitions-in-windows)

I plan to use Ubuntu, but I don't know if I can transfer files from windows to Ubuntu. Any help please?

Comment: @UriHerrera Not a duplicate, he's asking about the other way around. Windows files > Ubuntu, not Ubuntu files > Windows.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Ubuntu on dual boot.

1) To transfer files from Windows to Ubuntu:

Well, you don't even need to =) Ubuntu can read NTFS partitions (Windows file system) you can browse your Windows drive without effort. (and of course, transfer files from Windows partition to Ubuntu partition)

2) To transfer files from Ubuntu to Windows:

Read the post suggested by *Uri Herrera*

Of course, you can also transfer files the ugly way, using an external storage, like USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

I dual boot ubuntu 10.10 and Windows 7, and I keep a Storage partition formatted to NTFS for any files that aren't OS specific. As mentioned by Galm, both Operating Systems can read it, so it eliminates the need for transferring and keeps a singular copy of everything regardless of where it was modified. You could follow Uri's link, but keeping a Storage partition has worked well for me.