# How to access files on Ubuntu partion from Windows XP?

Tags: files, windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read ext4 and btrfs partitions in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-and-btrfs-partitions-in-windows)

I've installed Ubuntu using the Wubi. Now I've Windows XP SP3 and Ubuntu running on the same machine. I want to access all the files that are on the Ubuntu partition, when I am using Windows XP.

How can I do it?