# How to view ubuntu files from windows?

Tags: mount, ext4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read ext4 and btrfs partitions in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-and-btrfs-partitions-in-windows)

How to view ubuntu files from windows.
 If i cant access ubuntu(it crashed badly). Files are important! Please help !