# How do I access Ubuntu filesystem from Windows on dualboot?

Tags: partitioning, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read ext4 and btrfs partitions in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-and-btrfs-partitions-in-windows)

I am dual-booting Ubuntu and Windows. When I'm in Ubuntu, the Windows partition is automatically mounted and I can browse it easily. However, when I'm in Windows I can't see the Ubuntu partition. How can I access it from Windows?

Answer (score 3):

Use Ext2Read. Free and easy in use.

Answer (score 3):

use [Linux Reader](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/),which is similar to Windows explorer. and have more features (disk imaging,etc)