# question about dual-booting/partitioning?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I'm looking into partitioning my hard drive between windows 8 and linux ubuntu. I've never done anything of the sort, so i'm wondering how it works.
If I save files while I'm running it as Ubuntu, will I be able to access those same files if I'm running it as Windows 8, say, the next day?

Comment: This question already has an [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-in-windows).

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu and Windows use different partition types. Windows cannot normally read ext4 partitions.

My solution to this is to create an extra NTFS partition where I keep my documents, pictures etc.

I modified /etc/fstab to automount this partition on boot.

Then I modified the ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs file to point them to the folders in the extra partition.

I did a similar procedure to tell Windows where are my documents, pictures etc folders.

Comment: Using a separate data-sharing partition is the best way to go, IMHO. Although Linux can access your Windows `C:` drive, doing so is risky -- Linux doesn't respect the Windows ownership and permissions, and if the Linux driver has a hidden bug, you could trash your Windows installation. These problems are minimized on a data-only partition. Personally, I'd use FAT for this if possible, since Linux's FAT driver is better than its NTFS driver; but FAT has file size limits (about 4GiB) that may make it impractical for some purposes, so NTFS may be the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

It takes [some work](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions) to see files in Ubuntu from Windows, but from inside Ubuntu it's really easy to access your Windows file structure.  And you can always store things online using Dropbox, Google Drive, or (I think) Ubuntu One.

Comment: Or locally on some USB device.