# Run Ubuntu Concurrently with Windows 7

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I already have a Windows 7 installed on my PC...
What I did was I Shrink the entire Volume out of my unified Hard disk which was of 750 GB.
Now I am getting a "Simple volume" as indication in my disk management and not a "Primary Volume"

My question is: 
I am using a Flash drive which I made bootable using the software available on Linux's website to install Ubuntu.
Is it necessary to have a Primary Volume in Windows 7 to mount Linux Ubuntu 12.04 concurrently with Windows 7?
Or I can do it with Simple volume as well?

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd163559.aspx) explains this better that I ever could. So much for "Simple". Thanks, Microsoft.

You probably have just one regular partition on the disk. You can check this with GParted - if the partition shows up normal, the filesystem type is detected, and the correct amount of used space and disk usage is displayed, that that is the case. You can feel free to install Ubuntu alongside Windows. Otherwise, you will have to repartition Windows somehow.

You can use a third party tool to [mount the Linux partition in Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-in-windows), but otherwise Windows will be unable to get any information whatsoever from the partition other than that it's there. However, Linux will see and use the Windows partition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open your boot menu and put your flash drive as the priority not the hard drive.  Here is a link to help you switch your boot priority. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12911.tips-for-configuring-your-bios-settings-to-work-with-windows-to-go.aspx Press the correct key for your computer when you see the first screen that shows up when you boot your computer and then switch your priority boot.  Scroll down to the middle-bottom of the link for your answer.

Comment: if my answer helped tick it up one