# Double boot-up alongside Windows 8 and my hard-drives are not showing in windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I've installed Ubuntu along with Windows 8. For that, I had to convert all of my hard drives from dynamic to basic. However, I did not face any problem in installing Ubuntu and it got successfully installed. But when I opened Windows, it was not showing any of the hard-drives apart from C (in which Windows is installed). Now, Ubuntu is showing all of my hard-drives and their data but I am not able to find my data and hard-drives in Windows. What should I do ?

Comment: This is to be expected - Ubuntu runs with the EXT4 (or EXT3) file system, which Windows does not support at all apart from using some special programs. See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-in-windows (possible duplicate)

Comment: ex2read is not working . It is asking me to make sure that i am running the application as an administrator .

Comment: Yes, it needs to be run under an administrative account. Right-click it and choose "run as administrator".

Comment: Does it work on windows 8 too ? Because i've read that it does not and also it really is not working for me . All it's showing is only C drive's data and not other's.

Comment: [Edit] your question and include the output of `sudo parted --list` and remember that windows isn't able to read linux partitions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't able to view Ubuntu partitions(ext4,ext3) on Windows.

See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-in-windows) question for how to read ext4 partitions in Windows.

Comment: Ex2read is not working in my case ..

Comment: you can't able to write into it,but you can able to read that.

Comment: Its not showing anything . The application itself is not opening

Comment: see http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-read-ext3ext4-linux-partition-from-windows-7.html

Comment: Does it work on windows 8 too ? Because i've read that it does not and also it really is not working for me . All it's showing is only C drive's data and not other's

Comment: yes it works on windows 8.