# Any File Manager for accessing files of linux from Windows?

Tags: windows, ext4, filemanager

Any File Manager for Windows that can read `ext` formatted disk?

Comment: This question is about Windows, not about Ubuntu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read ext4 partitions in Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-in-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ext2fsd is a pretty good program.

Comment: will it mount `ext4` file system?

Comment: Yes it will, read-only by default.  It can be forced to write files as well.

Answer (score 0):

Total commander with Linux file system extension does great job.

http://www.ghisler.com/plugins.htm