# Unable to see ubuntu partition on windows

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows-7

I have dual-booted windows 7 and ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop. I can browse files stored in windows partition in ubuntu os but I cannot browse or see ubuntu partition in 'my computer' in windows. Please help how can I access my files of ubuntu partition in windows 7 partition?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-in-windows is a closed question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu is most likely using `ext3` or `ext4` filesystem format. Windows can not recognize this format and will not interact will drives/partitions using `ext*` filesystem.

To access your files between both systems, you can create and additional `fat32` partition on the drive and have it automatically mount in both OSes. AFAIK `fat32` is the best filesystem format for interoperability between Linux and Windows.