# Linux partion not showing in Windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows

Hey i recently installed Ubuntu gnome and the partion i made for it is not showing in windows. When i go to drivers it just says my C drive is the same size as before installing windows. Is this a problem? Is is possible that windows might override my linux partion. Or is this not a problem at all and is it just windows being windows...

Comment: Not a problem at all. Windows just can't read ext4(I guess it's being Windows). If you need to read ext4, check the link provided by gvbk1996 or read http://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-in-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux partition will not show up in Windows. Windows uses NTFS which cannot find ext4 which Ubuntu uses. There is a program called ext2read which can find Linux Partition in Windows. Link https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/?source=dlp