# How can I get a external hard drive with Ubuntu 16.04 to appear in Windows?

Tags: 16.04, windows

I have an External Hard Drive with Ubuntu 16.04 installed, is there any way I can access the files on it from Windows 10? I need some of the files on the hard drive to be accessible on both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read ext4 partitions in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-in-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read ext2, ext3 and ext4 partitions from Windows using ext2explore:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/files/latest/download