# Where are Ubuntu Files in (C:) drive in windows?

Tags: 12.04, windows-8, filesystem, filemanager

I have installed Ubuntu in C: drive of windows as dual boot(and not in a different drive). I want to know whether ubuntu files can be accessed from within windows or not and how and where can they be accessed. Thank you.

edit- my PC is not UEFI enabled. and ubuntu is not a wubi install.

Comment: is it a wubi install?

Comment: By default, Ubuntu formats its partitions with the ext4 filesystem. If you've installed Ubuntu alongside Windows on a separate partition on the disk (rather than inside the Windows partition with Wubi, or some other method), and you want to access those files from Windows, you'll need to either install ext2/3/4 filesystem drivers in the Windows system -- see [How to read ext4 partitions in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-in-windows) -- or put the specific files and folders you want to share on a separate partition both systems can natively read.

Comment: But I have installed ubuntu alongside windows on same partition. and it isnt a wubi install

Comment: You have used `windows-8` as a tag. How you managed to install Ubuntu on a UEFI enabled system inside C: drive? It means you created a free space from C: drive. Right? What steps did you followed?

Comment: I dont think my pc is uefi enabled. How can i check?

Comment: *"I have installed ubuntu alongside windows on same partition"* No you haven't. You've either accidentally overwritten Windows or you've partitioned it. So if you boot windows, go to My Computer and look for another drive - the ubuntu files are there. It's the same physical disk, but two separate partitions.

Comment: Similar superuser.com question is [How to read ext4 partitions on Windows?](http://superuser.com/q/37512/576184). If it is Wubi, use a program which can open image file `C:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you have followed [this(how to install ubuntu alongside pre-installed copy of Windows 8)](https://askubuntu.com/a/521195/171636). If yes then should have a bootable Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.
Now coming to your question; you can use Disk Internals Linux Reader. Here is the link:
http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/

Comment: According to this answer, a different partition is created for ubuntu installation. I have ubuntu and windows both installed on same partition.

Comment: can I still use Disk Internals Linux Reader tool?

Comment: It can read Ext2/3/4 So I'm sure that you can use it. :) If the answer helped and solved your querry then please accept it as an answer. An up vote would be cordially welcomed.

Comment: @KashyapC.Kotak I use linux-reader on same partition with Wubi method, too. Choose `Drives` - `Mount Images` - `Raw Images` and file name `C:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk`

Comment: its not a wubi install.