# How to see files and folders inside of ubuntu from windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, filesystem

I've run into a problem. Ubuntu grub has crashed, and system boots into Windows automatically. I have tried **boot-repair**  but Ubuntu doesn't even show up in **bcedit** command on Windows.

Anyways how can I see files and folders of Ubuntu partition from Windows 10 that I installed on Ubuntu?

I have a file I need to recover because I was working on it for a client.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try booting from live USB/DVD to access the partitions formatted `ext4`.

Comment: How to access Linux file systems from Windows is really a question about Windows which is off topic here but fine over on [SU]. Alternatively you can boot an Ubuntu live system (from a DVD or USB drive) and recover the files with that.

Comment: @DavidFoerster That's what I did, I got my files off of the partition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read ext4 partitions in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

You can install **DiskInternals Linux Reader** which supports many Linux partition.

- Ext2/3/4
- ReiserFS
- Reiser4 HFS
- HFS+ FAT
- exFAT NTFS
- ReFS
- UFS2

You can See and recover files from Linux Partition.

[image]You can recover your file from there.
See this link to download: https://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/

Comment: Sorry but answers that are Windows based are off-topic ;-)

Comment: This is old, proprietary software without support for operating systems that still receive vendor support themselves. Windows XP went EOL in 2014 and Vista even earlier than that. -1