# Installing Ubuntu Server on separate partition

Tags: server

I currently have 3 separate drives on my desktop pc and I'm looking to install an Ubuntu server on one of the drives partitioned to 400GB. Would I be able to install and access it from my windows installation? Or would I only have access to it via the partition itself?

Comment: By default windows knows how to access windows file systems (eg. NTFS, FAT), but Ubuntu will want to install to EXT, XFS or other file-systems that are not native to windows (like NTFS isn't native to Ubuntu), so unless you add drivers to allow it to happen, no it won't work as I imagine you hope it'll work. Usually users have partitions that both can use for transfer of files, but the best situation for you will depend on your wants/needs  (in what is called dual-boot)

Comment: Access Windows *files* from Linux, yes.  Access Linux *files* from Windows, no.  There is another way, and that's to run VirtualBox with a RAW disk in Windows, but it's very complicated and completely unsupported. (Even if I have managed to do it a couple of times out of necessity. :-p)

Comment: Related: [How to read ext4 partitions in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

After some looking around I came to the conclusion to run a virtual instance via VirtualBox and have it running in the background so that I can access it via the server itself or externally if needed. Until, or if, Windows gets support to be able to look into Linux files without complications, this will work