# Problems with Ubuntu partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 dual-boot with windows and gave it 520 Gb.
But Windows won't see the Ubuntu partition and it still thinks that it has 1Tb of disk space.

Comment: Windows never sees Ubuntu partitions.

Comment: Will Windows just break Ubuntu partition?

Comment: The question is totally unclear. Windows can't read or write to/from Linux partitions. So it is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: So if I write smth to disk from Windows It can break Ubuntu?

Comment: No, it can't break anything. Windows won't write to Ubuntu partition. Unless you try to amend partitions from Windows.

Comment: Thats nice, thx.

Comment: "Windows not seeing Ubuntu partition" is a Windows problem. Ubuntu cannot solve a Windows problem.

Comment: I disagree @user535733. After installing Ubuntu, all my windows problems were solved ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read ext4 partitions in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/)