# Create a partition when dual booting

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I'm dual booting from my SSD. Since my SSS is relatively small, I have a HDD for data storage. I have only 30GB for my Linux on the SSD and therefore need to create space on HDD, native to Ubuntu. I have created 2 partitions on the HDD from Windows and have approx 200Gb free unallocated space on HDD for my data. Since I am relatively new to this, I have two questions:

1. How do I safely create a Drive/Partition native to Ubuntu. I was about to use parted in terminal and make a partition but wasn't sure if it will damage any of my other data.
2. Is the drive/partition created from Linux readable from Windows and can I use it as a shared drive?

Comment: Years ago when dual booting Windows (XP) and Linux I had both a shared NTFS data partition and Linux formatted data partition. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk If using NTFS you have to make sure Windows fast start up is off, & Windows updates may turn it back on. And mount with good parameters. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/598813/sharing-a-partition-between-windows-and-linux-throws-permission-errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read ext4 partitions in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-in-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a partition using *only* unallocated space should not damage any other data on the drive.

Standard Linux filesystems are ext4, which can not be read by windows. If you wish to share the drive between Windows and Linux, format the partition with NTFS, which can be read and used by both Windows and Linux.